# Android session token handling

Tags: android, android-security

My android application has to maintain the session using token mechanism. Can someone tell me where to "securely" store the session token on the device? Is keychain mechanism introduced in Android 4.3 used by dev community for storing tokens?

Comment: It would be good idea to use AccountManager => https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Comment: I think this is different from what I'm seeking to know

Comment: You need save your access token for requesting data from the server? If yes => you should use it.